# Populate Buttons With Database Values c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi Guys okay so i have a database for this we will use a simple database.txt as reference

```
Text Database For Population 
Peter,Pan
James,Dean
Hal,lo
Calc,exe
Mad,Hatter
Patterson,Matthiew
```

I want to be able to add a button containing for example

```
 [Peter] , [James], ext ext
```

For Each Read Out Of The Database How Would I Pressure the population in this instance considering i have to create a button for each new name that is read from the database

Thanks In Advance

P.S.
Initially i Used a dropdown with the following code

```
        List<MDB.Userdb> packObjects = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MDB.Userdb>();
        string colname = "UserRef";
        try
        {
            packObjects = MDB.User.RetrieveList();


            if (!dgvData.Columns.Contains(colname))
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                cb.DataPropertyName = colname;
                cb.Name = colname;
                cb.HeaderText = colname;
                cb.DataSource = packObjects;
                cb.ValueMember = "Idx";
                cb.DisplayMember = "UserName";
                dgvData.Columns.Add(cb);
            }
            else
            {
                //refresh data in drop down
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ocb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvData.Columns[colname];
                ocb.DataPropertyName = colname;
                ocb.Name = colname;
                ocb.HeaderText = colname;
                ocb.DataSource = packObjects;
                ocb.ValueMember = "Idx";
                ocb.DisplayMember = "UserName";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Retrieve User Detials " + ex.Message, "Retrieve User Detials", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Notes:
WinForms
c#
.Net4.0

Comment: What I got from it is : You want to create button for all the person present in you text database right? Previously you have done it with Drop down.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah you are correct this is what im attempting to do

Comment: What all you tried? googling? any links you referred? please paste them here.

Comment: I have tried googeling but im usure on how to approach this this is why I asked the question  should I create an event with the buttons header size and parameters and just read the names out of a database into anlit and add them to the button one by one ?

Comment: Any links you visited please paste here.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82785s1h(v=vs.80).aspx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678249/c-sharp-array-of-buttons  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406868/c-sharp-add-controls-to-panel-in-a-loop

Comment: I am looking into it, update you soon.

Comment: Below Insteadof `for loop` you can use `foreach loop` the list that you are getting from your database and you can keep you own logic for the locations os button you want to keep.

`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Button newPanelButton = new Button();
                newPanelButton.Name = "txtRuntime" + i;
                newPanelButton.Text = "Runtime"+i;
                newPanelButton.Location = System.Drawing.Point.Add(new Point((i+(i*100)),(i+(i*100))),new Size(20,20));// your logic
                
                this.Controls.Add(newPanelButton);
            }`

Comment: @SandeepKushwah Please Post This As An Answer So i Can Set As Answered Thanks This Works Just Need to Modify The Points A Little Bit

Comment: Okay I will post my answer. Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Button newPanelButton = new Button();
            newPanelButton.Name = "txtRuntime" + i;
            newPanelButton.Text = "Runtime"+i;
            newPanelButton.Location = System.Drawing.Point.Add(new Point(4 + i * 307, 4), new Size(20, 20));// here make use of your logic.

            this.Controls.Add(newPanelButton);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader menu = new StreamReader("database.txt");
        int repetition = 0;

        while (!menu.EndOfStream)
        {
            Button dynamicbutton = new Button();
            dynamicbutton.Click += new System.EventHandler(menuItem_Click);
            dynamicbutton.AutoSize = true;
            dynamicbutton.Text = menu.ReadLine();
            dynamicbutton.Visible = true;
            dynamicbutton.Location = new Point(4 + repetition * 307, 4);
            dynamicbutton.Height = 24;
            dynamicbutton.Width = dynamicbutton.Text.Length * 20;
            dynamicbutton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            dynamicbutton.ForeColor = Color.White;
            dynamicbutton.Font = new Font("Arial", 7);
            dynamicbutton.Show();
            splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamicbutton);
            repetition++;
        }
        menu.Close();
```

This Does The Trick With A Few Extra Things In The MenuItem_Click Event i Can Also Retrieve The Name Of The Button And So Forth

Comment: I have cheked this solution but it not working properly.. there is problem on `new point` line. So replace that line by what I have suggested.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah i did add the point you suggested and it came up as this    peter {EnterTab] james{enterTab] where this one does not doe this but please do post your answer as an answer so i can mark this as resolved

Comment: I am happy that you finally got what you were looking for. :)